# Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token while Running react app

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

I have getting an error in `console.log` while running react app

Here is my app **useEffect**:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(`/api/foodies/${name}`);
      const body = await result.json();
      console.log(body);
      setFoodieInfo(body);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [name]);
```

My error is: `uncaught (in promise) syntaxerror: unexpected token < in json at position 0`

How to fix this?

Comment: What is the format of the response? It seems like the 'result' is not a JSON.

Comment: Its json formated

Comment: Is it your own api? If it is a public api, can you provide the url for it? I still think there is a typo or a trailing comma in the end or something like that. Or maybe you are returning html, so a '<' token. Please check it properly once.

Comment: yes its my own api, i create it using express js.

Comment: I have set `http://localhost:8000` server proxy in `package.json` also

Answer (score 0):

`result` returns html instead of json. run `console.log(result.text())`, most likely there will be a description of the error.